# Error trying to render the index.html that ng build generates with node and express

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I want to deploy an application that I perform with the MEAN stack on Heroku, but I encounter 1 problem.

1. I have this folder structure, my node server, with a public folder, where is the dist / fronted folder and all the files generated by Angular's ng build --prod, it works when I start the server and browse normally, but if I refresh the page or write a route myself, I get these errors:

[Errores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t3mr.png)

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

If your are building a MEAN stack, you probably have a **server.js** or **index.js** or **app.js** as an entry point to your application. An SPA by definition manages all the routes within the router configuration. But if you try to refresh or type a route yourself, it is like you were trying to access that folder on the server (ex: [www.mywebsite.com/about](http://www.mywebsite.com/about), here the folder about might not exist on the server, it is just known by your Angular app)

My suggestion is that you try to add this fix to the **app.js** (or server.js or app.js) file, so all unexisting routes or refresh go back to your index.html:

```
// Check your port is correctly set:
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Is saying express to put everything on the dist folder under root directory
// Check the folder to fit your project architecture
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/dist"));

// RegEx saying "capture all routes typen directly into the browser"
app.get(/.*/, function(req, res) {
    // Because it is a SPA, all unknown routes will redirect to index.html
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/dist/index.html");
});

app.listen(port);
```

This guy shows full deploy on Heroku with Angular: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBfcbb07Tqk

Hope it works for you!